# Jquery render different data according to body id value

Tags: jquery

I would like to load data according to the body id value, here is the code:

```
<body id="CN">
....
<body>
```

and the Jquery will take the value "CN" and load content,
the format of the content is below:

```
    <div class="menu">
    <div class="links">
    {module_menu,1032883}
    </div>
    </div>
```

the {module_menu,1032883} is the part I want to change, value "1032883" means "CN" and I have the below array:

```
{module_menu,14623} for "AU"
{module_menu,1022165} for "CA"
{module_menu,1032883} for "CN"
{module_menu,1014746} for "US"
```

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var id = document.body.id,
    dict = {
        AU: '{module_menu,14623}',
        CA: '{module_menu,1022165}',
        CN: '{module_menu,1032883}',
        US: '{module_menu,1014746}'
    };

dict[id] && $('.links').text( dict[id] );
```

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9dSq8/